# text-decoration Color of underline changes if email is forwarded

Tags: html, css, email

This is a piece of the code for an email I am sending out. I have noticed that when the email gets sent out originally, the line under the text will follow the color i picked for the text. However if the message is forwarded, the text will stay red, while the underline reverts to black.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: underline; color: #f60b31; padding: 10px; line-height: 18px " align="center">
```

Comment: Is the text very short or are the breakpoints known?  If so, you may be able to use border-bottom instead of underline (wrapping the text in a span if need be).